# WordPress: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\

Tags: php, html, wordpress

This is my first major WordPress site from absolute scratch. My PHP skills are only starting out and this is the error I am getting. I know what the problem is, I just don't know how to write this block of PHP code correctly and would appreciate some help please.

As far as I have read, I cannot put html markup into a block of PHP code like I have done here which is odd, as all the example WP Loops I have seen has HTML markup in it.

```
            <?php
            /**
             * Template Name: Home Page
             *
             * This Full Width template removes the primary and secondary asides so that content
             * can be displayed the entire width of the #content area.
             *
             */


                // calling the header.php
                get_header();

                // action hook for placing content above #container
                thematic_abovecontainer();

            ?>

                    <div id="container">

                        <?php thematic_abovecontent(); ?>

                        <div id="content" class="home-content">

                            <?php

                            // calling the widget area 'page-top'
                            get_sidebar('page-top');

                            the_post();

                            thematic_abovepost();

                            ?>

                            <div id="post-<?php the_ID();
                                echo '" ';
                                if (!(THEMATIC_COMPATIBLE_POST_CLASS)) {
                                    post_class();
                                    echo '>';
                                } else {
                                    echo 'class="';
                                    thematic_post_class();
                                    echo '">';
                                }

                                // creating the post header
                                // thematic_postheader();

                                ?>

                                <div class="entry-content">

                                    <?php

                                    the_content();

                                    wp_link_pages("\t\t\t\t\t<div class='page-link'>".__('Pages: ', 'thematic'), "</div>\n", 'number');

                                    edit_post_link(__('Edit', 'thematic'),'<span class="edit-link">','</span>') ?>

                                </div>
                            </div><!-- .post -->
                            <div class="featureBlocks">
                                <div class="news">
                                    <div class="featTitle">
                                        <h3>News <br />& Events</h3>
                                        <div class="featSubTitle">What's happening in the world of Process Engineering</div>
                                        <div class="clear"></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <?php 
                                        query_posts('cat=4&posts_per_page=1');
                                        if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
                                            the_title();
                                            the_content();
                                            /*<a href='<?php the_permalink(); ?>' rel='bookmark' title='Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>'><?php the_title(); ?></a>*/
                                        endwhile; endif;
                                        // Reset Query
                                        wp_reset_query();
                                    ?>
                                </div>
                                <div class="research">
                                    <div class="featTitle">
                                        <h3>Research <br />Highlights</h3>
                                        <div class="featSubTitle">Find out what exciting research is happening Process Engineering</div>
                                        <div class="clear"></div>
                                    </div>

                                    <?php 
                                        query_posts('cat=5&posts_per_page=1');
                                        if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
                                            <strong>the_title();</strong>
                                            the_content();
                                        endwhile; endif;
                                        // Reset Query
                                        wp_reset_query();
                                    ?>
                                </div>
                                <div class="studentStories">
                                    <div class="featTitle">
                                        <h3>Student <br />Stories</h3>
                                        <div class="featSubTitle">Student life at the Department of Process Engineering</div>
                                        <div class="clear"></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <?php 
                                        query_posts('cat=6&posts_per_page=1');
                                        if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
                                            the_title();
                                            the_content();
                                        endwhile; endif;
                                        // Reset Query
                                        wp_reset_query();
                                    ?>
                                </div>
                                <div class="clear"></div>
                            </div>
                        <?php

                        thematic_belowpost();

                        // calling the comments template
                        thematic_comments_template();

                        // calling the widget area 'page-bottom'
                        get_sidebar('page-bottom');

                        ?>

                        </div><!-- #content -->

                        <?php thematic_belowcontent(); ?> 

                    </div><!-- #container -->

            <?php 

                // action hook for placing content below #container
                thematic_belowcontainer();

                // calling footer.php
                get_footer();

            ?>
```

I'd appreciate it if someone could show me what I am doing wronf.
Many thanks!

Comment: The error message should also show a line number. Which is it and where is it in the code? (Edit: never mind - SO's syntax highlighting is showing it already, look at the 6th line from the bottom up)

Comment: Hi Pekka. It's to do with using <h1>the_title()</h1>. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone else managed to answer my question on another forum. Kash, I hope this works for you too.

```
<?php query_posts('cat=5&posts_per_page=1');
    if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();?>
    <strong><?php the_title();?></strong>
    <?php the_content();
    endwhile; endif;
?>
```

Thanks everyone else who pitched in! :)

Answer (score 4):

You have an unquoted string inside a `<?php ?>` block. Anything inside these blocks is interpreted as PHP syntax instead of raw HTML.

This line:

```
<h1>the_title();</h1>
```

Should probably be something like:

```
echo '<h1>' . the_title() . '</h1>';
```

Here, we concatenate `<h1>`, the output of `the_title()` and `</h1>` together to form a single string.

The syntax error pertains to the first `<` present in the `<h1>` tag. As it's not valid PHP syntax in the context it's in (being inside `<?php ?>` tags), it throws an error. As Pekka says, SO's syntax highlighting picks this up almost instantly.

You should check your code more thoroughly and find an editor with syntax highlighting or turn it on if you already have a capable one. The PHP errors usually give a line number. Find the line, and work out what the error is.

---

In the problem outlined in the comments (this: `<strong>the_title();</strong>` throwing an error), PHP is again encountering unquoted *string literals*. `<strong>` is perfectly invalid PHP syntax, because you haven't quoted it into a string.

This:

```
<strong>the_title();</strong>
```

Needs to become this:

```
echo '<strong>' . the_title() . '</strong>';
```

Please consider reading up on basic PHP syntax such as this; it's a trivial problem and is covered by many tutorials.

Comment: Could it possibly be because it's within another PHP block of code? (which I have not posted here). Thing is, I am working off example Loops and unless I am overlooking something, there's nothing different other than the surrounding PHP code. Also, I am using Dreamweaver so syntax color is on :)

Comment: Please see my edits. Are you saying you have a `<?php ?>` block inside _another_ `<?php ?>` block?

Comment: Hi JamWaffles. I've been away from this project for a little while and back but with the same issue again. I've reposted my PHP snippet. This time as it is in the file. The problems lays in the <strong>the_title();</strong> about half way down in the snippet. I think I may not be understanding the use of html tags inside PHP blocks but I am trying follow other examples from the actual WP site where they ARE using <h1> <strong> etc

Comment: I've edited my answer. Have a look at the new stuff on the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

As a newbie, I would like to use something like that:

```
                        <div class="news">
                            <div class="featTitle">
                                <h3>News <br />& Events</h3>
                                <div class="featSubTitle">What's happening in the world of Process Engineering</div>
                                <div class="clear"></div>
                            </div>
                            <?php 
                                query_posts('cat=4&posts_per_page=1');
                                if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
                            ?>
                                    <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
                                    <?php the_content(); ?>
                                    <a href='<?php the_permalink(); ?>' rel='bookmark' title='Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>' ><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                            <?php 
                                    endwhile; endif;
                                // Reset Query
                                wp_reset_query();
                            ?>
                        </div>
```

Wrapping only php code inside `<?php CODE ?>` tag.